# Need sql statement to join two lists of data into one with one common variable

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

I have this table with columns Patient # and Adverse Event:

```
0101      Headache  
0101      Vomiting  
0105      Pink eye 
0201      Fever  
0201      Skin Rash  
0201      Cold  
0204      Coughing
```

And a second table with columns Patient # and Medication:

```
0101      Aspirin  
0201      Tylenol  
0201      Hydrocortisone  
0201      Midol  
0201      Benedryl  
0201      Advil  
0203      Ginkgo Biloba  
0204      Advair  
0204      Triaminic
```

I would like a SQL query that would combine the 2 lists like this:

```
0101      Headache    Aspirin  
0101      Vomiting   
0105      Pink eye      
0201      Fever      Tylenol  
0201      Skin Rash  Hydrocortisone  
0201      Cold       Midol  
0201                 Benedryl  
0201                 Advil  
0203                 Ginkgo Biloba
0204      Coughing   Advair
0204                 Triaminic
```

Basically just dumping the contents of the 2 tables together by patient # (no relationship between adverse event and medication)

Comment: this is a simple join between tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simple joins will not give you the result you need to have a `row number partitioned by patient`:

```
select nvl(t1.patient,t2.patient),t1.adverse,t2.medication
from (select patient,
             adverse, 
             row_number() over (partition by patient order by patient) rn 
      from tbl1) t1
full outer join (select patient,
             medication, 
             row_number() over (partition by patient order by patient) rn 
      from tbl2) t2
on t1.patient= t2.patient
   and t1.rn=t2.rn
   order by 1,2
```

Answer (score 1):

The full outer join will give you your desired result:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Patients FULL OUTER JOIN Medication
     ON Patients.PatientsNumber=Medication.PatientsNumber
```

Comment: Thanks for your response...I tried using the above code but it yields a Cartesian join--it matches every adverse event with every medication for that patient...so if there are 2 AEs and 4 meds for a patient, the result is 8 rows--I would want 4 rows, the first 2 contain the first 2 AEs and Meds, then the last 2 would only contain the remaining 2 meds.

Answer (score 1):

Your table definition is wrong. Patient # 0101 appears twice on table one and only once in table 2. How would you know if aspirin was the correct medication to Headache or vomiting? In this case the joins sugested will give you the same medicament to both cases.

Comment: I actually do not want to try and match up the adverse events and medications...just list them alphabetically side by side for each patient--no relationship except patient number...so the result would be, by patient, an alphabetical list of AEs next to an alphabetical list of medications.--I know it is weird...